# Microsoft Edge: Manage preferences button

Tags: security, microsoft-edge, updates, preferences

### Microsoft Edge: Manage Preferences

After the new update, this new button comes up "Manage preferences" on the left bottom corner. I can not find anything about it on the Microsoft website. It says it's powered by OneTrust. I am wondering if I have installed something. Does anyone know about it?

[image: m]

Comment: It apperaed to me as well. I would recommend you post this question to reddit or quora though. It may be removed from Stack Overflow

Comment: I did not encounter this pop-up window in the latest chromium Edge (Version 92.0.902.67), does it appear every time I open the browser? If this is the case, I think you can try [the answer in this case](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/edge-browser-tab-privacy-statement/m-p/1847756) and try its solution. If I misunderstood something, could you provide more details?

Comment: They have removed this now. I am not sure what was it exactly. It was on the main screen in the edge browser.

Comment: @vixalien I do not care about it. I was curious to know about it so i posted.